# multi-friend-selector does not show up on internet explorer

Tags: php, facebook

I have just developed a facebook application. Most of it works fine but the multi-friend-selector does not show up on internet explorer.

Although Firefox and Google Chrome working fine it does not appear on IE. Also there is not any error messages.

Here is my code for multi-friend-selector:

```
<?php
          // Prepare the invitation text that all invited users will receive.
          $content = "<fb:name uid=\"".$me."\" firstnameonly=\"true\" shownetwork=\"false\"/> <a href=\"http://apps.facebook.com/".$app_url."/\">".$app_name."</a> is cool bla bla. \n".
                        "<fb:req-choice url=\"".$app_base . $app_url."/index2.php?firs=fb{$me["id"]}\" label=\" ".$app_name." Invite your friends!\"/>";



          ?>



    <fb:serverFbml style="width: 760px;" width="760px">
    <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml width="760px">

    <fb:request-form
            action="http://facebookAppUrl/<? echo $invite_href; ?>"
            method="POST"

            invite="true"
            type="<? echo $app_name; ?>"
            content="<? echo htmlentities($content, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>">

            <fb:multi-friend-selector
                    actiontext="<? echo $app_name; ?>' invite your friends!"
                    exclude_ids="<? echo $friends; ?>"
                    style='width: 760px'
                    showborder="false"
                     />

    </fb:request-form>

    </fb:fbml>
    </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
```

I have just checked all relevant posts in developer forums of facebook but no luck. I am not able to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Did you include fb namespace tags? Is this example works for you: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector If ti does then you need to compare what's different in your version

Comment: oh! thanks a lot you saved my time. i just added xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" and it worked. please post this comment as answer so that i can approve it correct answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was in not including fb namespace tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Again, thank you very much. IE and Safari needs namespace explicitly defined.